# Pastel 12 Journals Terminating Error, Status 46

Tags: windows-7

I have a Problem With Pastel 12.1.6 And Windows 7 32bit SP1.
The problem is that when you try to add a entry in the "journals" function the program crashes, with this error message:

[image]

I think this may be a fault with Pervasive 10.3 Workgroup(this is some kind of Program You install that allows Pastel to communicate with the Server database)

Here Is the Things That I have Tried:

1. Contacting the Developer, unfortunately the developers do not have good after sales support, basically they said that if we want support we need to buy the new version and signup for one year "Support".This will cost approximately $2200 and we do not have the funds for this update.
2. Googling around. This turned up a fix of sorts that requires you to run Start>Pervasive>Utilities>function executor , then select the file that is shown in the error and just leave it open (it this case the error file is accbtn.000). This however does not work for every File.
3. Installing Windows XP 32, This Works Great the error is no more, but i would like to upgrade at least to Windows 7 for a multitude of reasons, first of being that the computer Passtel is installed on has a SLIC for Windows 7 32 Professional.

So I would like to know how to fix this issue, if it can be fixed.

Comment: do you know which file does pastel access when adding an entry ?

Comment: I believe it would be accbtn.000 but i would have to check with ProcMon.

Comment: check it, whatever the file it tries to access , I think  windows-7 have restricted permission for its access(that's why it works on xp I think)

Comment: Ok So i just had a look it does seem to be accbtn.000, To rule out the possibility of other programs intervening i have installed this on a VM Win7.Anyway All the other functions works properly the file accntn.000 is fully accessible by the Test rig i setup.That File is also used by other functions without fail(procmon shows calls to it multiple times).

Comment: Sage does not have good documentation on pastel errors. all the answers i have is by trial and error or of s bookkeepers blog post.

Comment: hmmm maybe windows-7 doesn't give good permisions to old programs(that work on old windows like xp), install an older version from those programs on the VM and try to access the file again, also try to run pastel in compatibility mode

Comment: Ok I will Try This, Note that i do have the UAC and Firewall Off just incase.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Pastel Consultant, and came across this question, even though its old. Its got to do with the shared Pastel folder on the machine its installed on.

Right click on that share and make sure all the read and write ticks are on. If not you will get a access denied error.

This also goes for the security tab on the shared properties, they must also be ticked for read and write.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems to work to sort this problem out is to go into the pastel folder and search for the file accbtn, cut it to whatever location you want and it works! No error.

Good luck!